# C# ejecutar código al terminar una función

Tags: c#, funciones, hilos

Tengo consumiendo un servicio externo repetidas veces dentro de una misma función.

```
...

A = FuncionB(P);

C = FuncionC(A);

...
```

Al realizar la ejecución en depuración no tengo problemas ya que ingreso de manera secuencial a ambos servicios, notar la dependencia de la respuesta de FuncionB.

Pero al ejecutar sin depuración me genera una excepción por no existir A.

Me pueden ayudar con alguna sugerencia para manejar esta parte del programa, ya que necesito que primero finalice la FuncionB para luego ir a FuncionC.

Este es el codigo de la aplicación:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage POST([FromBody]List<AnotacionFacturaIN> lstIEntity)
    {
     List<RegistroFactura> lstEntity = new List<RegistroFactura>
...
LstEntity = Module.GetProcesaFactura(lstIEntity);
...
LstConsultaFactura = Module.GetConsultaFactura(LstEntity);
...
}
```

Comment: Deberías enseñarnos más el código ya que no sabemos si estás haciendolo de manera síncrona, asíncrona, usando task, usando threads, etc. De todas maneras suena a que tienes un problema de sincronización entre hilos.

Comment: Si supiéramos qué tipo de hilo utilizas podríamos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Hola, no uso hilos es código dentro de una función de post.

Comment: Y el problema sucede con más de una petición o en el mismo request, utilizas tus clases A y C como estáticas?

Comment: Como la primera petición es a un servicio externo y la segunda tambien me parece como es dependiente se ejecuta la segunda sin datos,devueltos de la primera

Comment: Podrías pasar la segunda función como un una función  coollback a la primera  y que cuando finalice la ejecute aqui te dejo un enlace de como se hace https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/843s5s5x(v=vs.110).aspx.                                                              Imagino que también podrías usar async y await te dejo otro enlace https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Gracias en efecto había un proceso async de un servicioexterno, el cual no lo puedo cobtrolar en linea, pero el callback que me mencionaron me sirvió para el js que si es async, gracias